# How to make php switch case check for type?

Tags: php, switch-statement, identity, equality

I want switch case to check with `===` rather than `==`.

```
<?php
$favcolor = "1";

switch ($favcolor) {
    case 1:
        echo "Your favorite color is red!";
        break;
    case "blue":
        echo "Your favorite color is blue!";
        break;
    case "1":
        echo "Your favorite color is green!";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, nor green!";
}
?>
```

This gives me:

```
Your favorite color is red!
```

But I want it to say green. How is that possible?

Comment: From the [manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php): "_Note that switch/case does loose comparison._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

> Note that switch/case does loose comparison.

You cannot achieve this using switch, consider using if - elseif - else in such case like:

```
if ( $favcolor === 1 )
    echo "Your favorite color is red!";
elseif ( $favcolor === "blue" )
    echo "Your favorite color is blue!";
elseif ( $favcolor === "1" )
    echo "Your favorite color is green!";
else
    echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, nor green!";
```